# Switch WM and compositor

Tags: arch-linux, kde, picom

I have a weird situation. I have kde plasma installed on my arch installation. I installed picom and awesomewm and would like to make the switch. But I am unable to find any existing resources to do this.

Comment: login-screen: bottom left corner: Desktop-Session:  (Select Window Manager) - is that what you are after? Optionally, if not, which Display Manager (I.e https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Display_Manager) do you use?

Comment: I think I have LightDM installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDDM -

Make sure auto login is not enabled, and check `/usr/share/xsessions/` for the files relevant to awesome. If they are there, then you should be able to select them from within SDDM. You can probably modify awesome's file to start picom, or you can put it in your `~/.profile`.

If you are not using SDDM, then I don't know how you are logging into KDE. Either you rigged something together in `~/.xinitrc` or you custom-installed a different display manager. Either way, if you understood what you did then, you should be able to fix it now.

If you need any more help with Arch Linux related things, check out their more Arch-centric forums on https://bbs.archlinux.org and use the wiki at https://wiki.archlinux.org.